# Android studio not launching after setting up Custom VM Options

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I recently thought of creating a "custom vm options" file in android studio, but I seem to have messed up something in the setup, resulting in following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Xms2048m
```

I am using Ubuntu for my development. I tried to locate the file but the 2 .vmoptions files present in the bin directory are studio64.vmoptions and studio.vmoptions and both these files do not contain "Xms2048m". I don't understand which file I am supposed to edit.From what I understand is that , I wrote Xms2048m instead of -Xms2048m (missed on the -), but where are the custom VM Options saved and how do I correct it?

Comment: Google `Android studio Custom VM Options`?

Comment: @Meo: Its nowhere mentioned where the generated custom vm options file gets saved.

Comment: See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544869.

Comment: @Roadblock the first link: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html#file_location

Comment: @Meo: I checked the directory, but the 2 .vmoptions file in the bin are studio64.vmoptions and studio.vmoptions, both of which do not contain Xms2048m

Comment: @CrazyCoder: Didn't know about config directories existence and their priorities. Found the file. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @Roadblock ... "Both configuration files are stored in the configuration folder for Android Studio. The name of the folder depends on your Studio version. For example, Android Studio 2.2 has the folder name AndroidStudio2.2. The location of this folder depends on your operating system:

Windows: %USERPROFILE%\.<CONFIGURATION_FOLDER>/
"

Comment: @Meo: Yes I just found out from CrazyCoder's comment. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution from the link posted in the comments. Turns out the file is saved in the hidden directory of Android studio configuration files i.e. at ~/.AndroidStudio/studio64.vmoptions. If you have configuration files here, then they are prioritised over the ones in the bin directory.

Comment: Thanks, for me i forgot to add the "m" in the config and Android Studio wasn't launching anymore. I was trying to revert the /bin configuration and it wasn't working. Updating the .AndroidStudio/studio64.vmoptions worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is solved.

But for anyone that is trying to find the `studio64.vmoptions`
I found it in `~/.config/Google/AndroidStudioX.X/studio64.vmoptions`

*replace the X.X with your android studio version*

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31224899)

Answer (score 0):

The file that got changed exist in the config directory:
`~/.AndroidStudoio3.1/config/studio64.vmoptions`
 and not in the bin directory of android studio. You can delete it and everything will get to normal. 
`rm .AndroidStudoio3.1/config/studio64.vmoptions` 

for more informations check this link https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869